# Does intel update their driver for GNU/Linux?

Tags: graphic-drivers, intel

I saw the release date of the latest HD4600 driver which is on intel's official website is on 2013/8/29, doesn't it mean that they haven't updated it for Linux since 2013/8/29?

Comment: Ubuntu? @JulianLai

Answer (score 1):

Intel drivers are open source and always the newest in repos.

See the links:

https://01.org/linuxgraphics

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads

Recommended reading:

[How do I install the latest Intel Linux Graphics?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1734/how-do-i-install-the-latest-intel-linux-graphics)

I guess you are looking at [this page](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/13815/Intel-Graphics-Drivers-for-Linux-)

Comment: Does it mean that no matter 14.04 or 15.10 of Ubuntu are running the same latest intel graphic driver?

Comment: the graphics installer doesn't support for 14.04

Comment: I am not sure about that but  may depends on kernel..