# Elemetary OS 0.4 Loki, How Do I Fix Screen Tearing

Tags: graphics

I am almost done using elementary OS due to all of the little issues setting it up. I have used between 40 and 50 different Linux distros in the last couple of years but elementary OS seems to be the single most difficult distro that I have used.

My current issue is screen tearing. It is not a new issue, this issue has been present since the minute that I installed elementary OS, but it is the newest issue that I tackling. The screen tearing in elementary OS is the worse that I have experienced in any Linux distro, and I do not know how to fix it. My system is very basic;

Intel i5 4690 Haswell CPU
Asus Z-170A motherboard 
Crucial SSD that elementary uses all by itself
Evga G2 550 power supply

If anybody can help me to completely eliminate this terrible screen tearing that I experience while scrolling through web pages on Firefox, I would appreciate it. Unfortunately I can not use Epiphany web browser because it was not compatible with my hardware and refused to work at all.

Thank you all. From reading this other post [How do I install the latest Intel Linux Graphics?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1734/how-do-i-install-the-latest-intel-linux-graphics?rq=1) I see that I am not alone in this situation.

Rocky Bennett

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you installed a 4690 into a 170 mobo

Answer (score 2):

Although the cause might of course be different, your description matches an issue I have resolved on my Asus Zenbook UX310UA-FC186R by installing a more up-to-date kernel from [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/). Instructions:

1. Select the folder corresponding to the kernel version you want to use (in my case 4.10.2 is working fine).
2. From the amd64 build download (* is the version number placeholder):

   - `linux-headers-*_all.deb`
   - `linux-headers-*-generic_*_amd64.deb`
   - `linux-image-*-generic_*_amd64.deb`
3. Install all three packages and reboot.

Note that in case the new kernel causes difficulties, you can still use Grub to reboot into the original one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion but unfortunately elementary OS Loki 0.4 comes with Linux Kernel 4.4, which is already more recent than Kernel 4.10.2.

Comment: I think you are confusing the version numbering. Split it as follows: MAJOR VERSION NUMBER . MINOR VERSION NUMBER . (and so on). In other words 4.4 and 4.10 correspond to the same major version with 4.10 having a more up-to date minor version (10 > 4). See https://www.kernel.org/ for details.

Comment: This is meant a reply to your answer below.
I see. In this case I agree that a kernel update might be the best way to tackle this. In case you are still on elementary, could you provide the following pieces of information: Your Xorg log and the outputs of lspci and dmesg?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was just looking at the link that you provided, thank you. I am reluctant to update my Kernel because my CPU is almost 3 years old and the installed Kernel that I am using is only a few months old. According to the release notes for elementary OS 0.4 Loki, the Kernel has been updated for support up to the 6th generation Skylake processor, and I am only running the 4th generation Haswell. I have recently used much older distros that used much older Kernels, but it was quite easy to update the graphics driver to support the Intel core architecture, but I have not figured out how to update the driver in elementary OS. Like I said in my first post, elementary OS is actually the most difficult distro that I have ever used, it is not intuitive at all. Thank you for the link because I did learn a lot.

P.S. I had to choose the answer option because my response had ran over the limit allowed by over 200 characters. Sorry, but I still need guidance on this.

Comment: After further reading, I see that there is no way to fix this issue. http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8489/intel-graphics-performance-on-loki  Because of this I will have to use a different distro.

Answer (score 0):

I am so sorry, I have a Z 97 A motherboard. I do not know what I was thinking or how I wrote the above. My apologies.